# Allow special characters in ng-pattern

Tags: html, angularjs, regex, special-characters

I am trying to allow some special characters in a field, these characters are the accented vowels (áéíóúÁEÍÍÓÚ), ÑñÇç to allow french and spanish names (i.e Nuño, José, François). My code goes like this:

```
ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z\_\-\&\`\#\. ]*$'áéíóúÁEÍÍÓÚÑñÇç"
```

And I have tried this too

```
ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z\_\-\&\`\´\#\. ]*$'\á\é\í\ó\ú\Á\É\Í\Ó\Ú\Ñ\ñ\Ç\ç]/"
```

but when I deploy it in the server, and inspect the field, it changes those characters into unknown characters, like shown below:

```
<input type="text" name="firstName" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-not-empty ng-valid-required ng-invalid-pattern ng-touched" ng-required="!userDetails.user.firstname" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z\_\-\&amp;\`\�'\#\. ]*$'\�\�\�\�\�\�\�\�\�\�\�\�\�\�/" ng-model="userDetails.user.firstname" aria-invalid="true">
```

How can I make the compiler to recognize the characters i need?

Thanks

Comment: have you explicitly specified the character encoding to one that has those characters?

Comment: yes, i added the meta     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

Comment: In general, `^[a-zA-Z\_\-\&\`\´\#\. ]*$'\á\é\í\ó\ú\Á\É\Í\Ó\Ú\Ñ\ñ\Ç\ç]` will never match anything. Did you mean `^[-a-zA-Z_&\`´#. áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚÑñÇç]*$` or `^[-a-zA-Z_&\`´#. \u0027\u00C1\u00C7\u00C9\u00CD\u00D1\u00D3\u00DA\u00E1\u00E7\u00E9\u00ED\u00F1\u00F3\u00FA]*$` ?

Comment: Thanks! it worked as expected

Answer (score 0):

/^[a-zA-Z_\-&`´#\. áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚÑñÇç]*$/ should work in you case - you don't need to place an escape literal (\) in front of a character doesn't need to escape.

Comment: The dot `.` inside classes doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: It has the same result:

<input type="text" name="firstName" class="form-control ng-not-empty ng-valid-required ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-pattern" ng-required="!userDetails.user.firstname" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z_\-&`�#\. ��������������]*$/" ng-model="userDetails.user.firstname" aria-invalid="false">

Answer (score 0):

As @sln commented, it needed the unicode characters, it works with

```
^[-a-zA-Z_&`´#. \u0027\u00C1\u00C7\u00C9\u00CD\u00D1\u00D3\u00DA\u00E1\u00E7‌​\u00E9\u00ED\u00F1\u‌​00F3\u00FA]*$
```

Answer (score 0):

If the charset/encoding of your html (can be set in browser, or in web server) is set to UTF8, you don't need above unicode conversion.